# Passing Select Option to POST request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm very new to web development and I'm trying to pass what the user has selected in a field called accesslevel_id to a POST request, so I can pass it to my database.  I'm following the example in my book, but it doesn't seem to work as intended.

My script is the following:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#accesslevel_id').on('change', function () {
      alert($('#accesslevel_id').val());
    });
  });
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" id="accesslevel_id" onchange="accesslevel_id" title="">
  <option>Facility</option>
  <option>Division</option>
  <option>Corporate</option>
  <option>Market</option>
  <option>Group</option>
</select>
```

When on the site and a user selects an option it currently displays None for my print function defined as `accesslevel_id = request.POST.get('accesslevel_id')`.  The next step, which i'm not at yet is to convert the option name into numbers to store into the database.  I'm looking for advice on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to post the value of option value when it changes right?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#accesslevel_id').on('change', function () {
        var accesslevel_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({url: "action-page", 
                data:"accesslevel_id="+accesslevel_id,
                type: "POST",
                success: function(result){
                   alert(result);
                }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: exactly what I needed, i checked further in the book and it had the ajax, it's poorly written thank you.